# starting a process to run from command line

Tags: command-line-arguments

I'm trying to make "[streamripper32](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/sr32/)" start on a schedule using Windows Task Manager.  I am able to get the application to start but not able to get it to start running.  I've tried every argument imaginable in the "actions" tab of task manager.

I am running windows vista